# Can't zoom close to object with small unit

Tags: 3d-view

When working with relatively small units (mm) and small object I am not able to zoom in so I can see the object. It looks like part of the view is obscured (as shown on screenshot).

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the 3d view press N and go to view and make clip start smaller:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for quick answer.